# does it make sense to use jms in same application

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

We are currently involved in building shopping cart web application in java.
The user will search for an product but it might be not available at moment.

We need to notify the user by email when the product is available.

Is it better to go with JMS or simply using thread job to solve this issue?

Comment: And what will happen with your thread job if your application restarts?

Comment: I assume that notification email data are stored inside db table say mail_notify, and when thread job sent email successfully it marks related row inside that table...does it work that way.